# Find $\int^{2}_{0} (x^2+1) d{\lfloor x \rfloor}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find $$\int^{2}_{0} (x^2+1) d{\lfloor x \rfloor}$$
where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer smaller than or equal to x.

I found this question in a book. After reading this question, I am now confused about what an integral is. 
Please try to clarify what this particular integral means and then solve it

Comment: $\mathrm d[x]$ is nonsense.

Comment: Can you please specify why it is nonsense?

Comment: It does look weird to me but I simply can't point out where it's wrong

Comment: @KennyLau It's a Stieltjes integral. Surely the floor function on $(a, b)$ is of bounded variation.

Comment: @KennyLau Because it is not. Simply apply integration by part.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out that it's a Stieltjes integral. I looked it up on Wikipedia and understood how to do the question. @SeanRoberson

Comment: @hellotinfish How can it be solved using integration by parts? Please add an answer

Comment: Sorry but I'm using my phone right now. I hate typing LaTeX on a phone. Maybe I'll do it later when I have my computer in front of me.

Comment: From what book did this come? What topic does that section cover?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I found it in a book which had questions from many topics. A question bank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose any partition $0=x_0<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n=2$ of the interval $[0,2]$ and note that the upper Reimann sum for this integral is $$\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k^2+1)(\lfloor x_k\rfloor-\lfloor x_{k-1}\rfloor)$$
Now note that if $x_k$ and $x_{k-1}$ both belong to either $[0,1)$ or $[1,2)$ then $\lfloor x_k\rfloor-\lfloor x_{k-1}\rfloor=0$. Can you do the rest?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Reimann sums. Could you please elaborate further?

Comment: @ArpitSaxena: Which definition of integrals are you working with, then?

Comment: I'm just a beginner in integration. I'm not familiar with the different definitions of integrals. I was introduced to integration as an antiderivative and evaluating definite integrals by using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: I got it after reading up on Riemann-Stieltjes integral. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts:
$$\int^2_0(x^2+1)d\lfloor x\rfloor=[(x^2+1)\lfloor x\rfloor]^2_0-\int^2_0\lfloor x\rfloor d(x^2+1)$$$$=10-\int^2_0\lfloor x\rfloor d(x^2+1)=10-2\int^2_0x\lfloor x\rfloor dx$$$$=10-2\int^1_0x\lfloor x\rfloor dx-2\int^2_1x\lfloor x\rfloor dx$$$$=10-2(0)-2\int^2_1x(1) dx=7$$

since $\lfloor x\rfloor=0$ for $x\in[0,1)$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor=1$ for $x\in[1,2)$